# How to remove the Done Bar above the number-pad in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, keyboard

How can I remove this bar from the Keyboard? Everywhere I looked I can't seem to find the answer. There's people trying to make it show but not to hide.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Current code:

```
<CustomInput
    keyboardType="number-pad"
    value={confirmationCode}
    onChangeText={(value) => setConfirmationCode(value)}
    placeholder={"••••••"}
    hidePlaceholder={true}
    maxLength={6}
    styleInput={styles.confirmationCodeStyleInput}
    autoFocusKeyboard={true}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this because I haven't seen it in any other places.

The way to do this is to add the following key/value to the `<Input />` component:

`inputAccessoryViewID="hideDoneButton"`

Then somewhere in the same render put the following:

`<InputAccessoryView nativeID="hideDoneButton"></InputAccessoryView>`

What this does is replace the top input accessory bar with your own bar. Since we are not adding any visual components to it then it will not show the bar at all.

Cheerios, I hope this save some time to other devs.

Answer (score 0):

try with returnKeyType='none', it should work